# List of all methods that throw an specific exception in a package

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I need a way to get a list of all methods that throw an specific exception in a package in java.

Preferably in eclipse but I'm open minded so any ide or text editor is fine, i was going to write a plugin for this but I'm sure there is already one out there.

Edit: I know that if i delete the try block all exceptions will be highlighted but i need a faster way to do it

Answer (score 3):

Use the Match Locations checkbox in the Java page of the Search dialog.

[image: The Search dialog's Java page's Match Location Selection popup]